# Determine whether W is a subspace of $V = P(t)$, the vector space of real polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am learning linear algebra from Schaum's outlines book. There is a solved example where $V = P(t)$ is the vector space of real polynomials. We define $W$ as:

$W$ consists of all polynomials with degree greater than equal to 6, and the zero polynomial.
Find whether $W$ is a subspace of $V$.
My approach:
take $q(t) = a*t^6 + t^2 + 1$ and r(t) = $(-a)t^6+t $. By definition of $W$ both $q(t), r(t) \in W$ but their sum
$q(t) + r(t) = ((a-a)*t^6 + t^2 + t + 1) = t^2 + t + 1\notin W$. Hence $W$ is not closed under $addition$ so W cannot be subspace.
But the book claims that $W$ is a subspace. What am I doing wrong? Could somebody please point me in correct direction. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a mistake in Schaum.  Which does not shock me.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for reply. Is Schaum an error prone book? I was told by a senior that it is good for learning lin algebra. I want to know if I should be ready for such surprises going ahead with Schaum

Comment: It's been many years since I've used Schaum's Outline Series, and things might have improved since then.  But back in the day they all were pretty bad at precision and rigor, but pretty good at computational or formula-manipulation exercises. It's clear you have the concept of linear subspace down pat.  Good work!

Comment: Most likely it was supposed to be that the degree was $\le 6$ instead of $\ge 6$. That would have been a subspace.